# C++ Calling a string from a struct stops the program

Tags: c++, matrix

I'm a beginner in C++. I appreciate any suggestions in which could improve my code but what I'm really looking for is an explanation as to why my current code isn't returning what I want.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


struct MATRIX {
  float values[1][1];
  string names;
};

MATRIX get_matrix(string name, MATRIX m){
  m.names = name;
  cout << "Enter values of 2x2 Matrix:" << endl;
  cin >> m.values[0][0];
  cin >> m.values[0][1];
  cin >> m.values[1][0];
  cin >> m.values[1][1];
  return m;
}
// end get_matrix1

MATRIX get_matrix2(string name2, MATRIX m2){
  m2.names = name2;
  cout << "Enter values of 2x2 Matrix:" << endl;
  cin >> m2.values[0][0];
  cin >> m2.values[0][1];
  cin >> m2.values[1][0];
  cin >> m2.values[1][1];
  return m2;
}


int main(){

string testname;
MATRIX matrixtest;
string testname2;
MATRIX matrixtest2;
cout << "Name 1st Matrix:" << endl;
cin >> testname;
MATRIX result = get_matrix(testname, matrixtest);




cout << "Name 2nd Matrix:" << endl;
cin >> testname2;
MATRIX result2 = get_matrix2(testname2, matrixtest2);



cout << "[" << result.values[0][0] << "," << result.values[0][1] << "]" << endl;
cout << "[" << result.values[1][0] << "," << result.values[1][1] << "]" << endl << endl;

cout << "[" << result2.values[0][0] << "," << result2.values[0][1] << "]" << endl;
cout << "[" << result2.values[1][0] << "," << result2.values[1][1] << "]" << endl << endl;

}
```

It's supposed to return the name of the matrix as well as its values. Whenever it hits the name member in **result** it just stops the program.

EDIT: Updated to current code

Comment: It looks weird to receive an argument (`m`, `m2`) and to ignore its value completely. Why not use local variables?

Comment: Unrelated: Typo. `cout << resutl.namee;` -> `cout << result.names;`

Comment: @user4581301 That typo means that the code here is *not* the code actually being run, because what's here won't compile.  Jose, can you please show the code that actually gives the issue you notice, and show what output you do get?

Comment: buffer overflow. You defined arrays of size one, but accessing second element.

Comment: The mark I eyeball is a weird thing. It spots the resutl, but not the namee. Compiler would get both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to specify *the number of elements*, not the maximum index, to declare arrays in C++.

With this declaration

```
  float values[1][1];
```

Only `values[0][0]` is avaliable.

The declaration should be

```
  float values[2][2];
```

Comment: The issue isn't calling the values from the array, my code seems to do that just fine. It's calling the string member.

Comment: @JoseP Accessing out-of-bounds of array is dangerous because it invokes *undefined behavior* and allows anything to happen. You must not do that.

Comment: @JoseP In practice, writing outside the array probably corrupts the string that happens to be stored just after it.

Comment: You guys were absolutely right, changing the array size did it!